# Setting up a web application to automatically run authenticated calls over HTTP to a remote website without repeated human authentication

Tags: authentication, encryption, passwords, xml-rpc

I want to be able to set up a web application to automatically (i.e. on a cron run) send a POST request to a remote website.  The remote website requires a username/password combination to be sent as part of the POST data.  I want the web application to be able to make the POST requests of the remote website without requiring the user to provide the password to be sent with the POST data, each time the request is made.

It seems to me that the only way to do this is to store passwords directly in the database, so that the cron run can execute a POST request that includes the password as part of its POST data.  Without storing the password in some form in the database, it seems it would be impossible to provide it in the POST data, unless the user provides it each time the request is made.

Question 1:  Am I mistaken and somehow overlooking something logical?
Question 2:  Assuming I have to store the passwords in the database, what is the safest procedure for doing so?  (MD5 and similar one-way encryption clearly will not work because I have to send an unencrypted password in the POST request.)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

a. if you don't know the password... you can't authenticate, that's the idea of a password !

b. if you need to know the password - you need to save it in a decryptable way - hence - less secured.

c. if you own the site, you can use a cookie with a very long timeout value, but - you still need to authenticate at least once.

d. unless you're guarding money / rocket science, you need to encrypt the password and store it in the DB and decrypt it every time before use, at least you are guarded from DB theft.

e. make sure you're authenticating over secure channel (as https) so the password will no be sent as clear text.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  So, it seems that I will need to store an encrypted version of the password in the database in order to do this.  Can you recommend a two-way encryption method that I can implement?  Do you know of any sources that describe how I would install such a method?  If it helps, I'm working with a Rails site deployed to Heroku.  (If it doesn't help, we can keep the problem in the abstract.)  Thanks so much!

Comment: +1 as it talks about cookies, be sure to handle as well the cookie storage as a login/password-post authentification is quite certainly based on sesions cookies. And everything is there. I'll add that a cron job could be run with another database access and another code as the web app, so you could store theses passwords in a place where only the cron job can access them (another table? db? file?).

Comment: @Morris - to your question - any encryption is good, it depends what are you guarding, and against who. a strong encryption is nice - but if you don't protect the key - it's worthless... now, where will you hide the key - eventually - you need to decide where your attacker will strike, and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

One good solution is probably to use SSL (i.e. HTTPS). You can create a certificate authority on the server side, then have this certificate authority sign a client certificate that you generate. Make sure the HTTP server is configured to trust the newly created certificate authority.

Once this is done, you should install the certificate on the client side. The client must present the certificate when talking to the HTTP server. You have to configure the HTTP server to require a trusted certificate when POSTing to your secure URLs.

Awesome example of how to do this with Apache HTTPD is posted [right here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ssl/ssl_howto.html#allclients)!

The document I linked doesn't describe how to set up the certificate authority and create self-signed certificates, but there are tons of examples out there, for example [here](http://www.tc.umn.edu/~brams006/selfsign.html).

This is a good solution because:

- no passwords are stored in the clear
- if the private key of the client's certificate is stolen or compromised, you can revoke it on the server side

The key here is that the **client** is providing its credentials to the server, which is the opposite of what is usually done in a browser context. You can also have the client trust your newly created certificate authority so that it knows it's talking to the right server and not a man in the middle.

Comment: This seems like the only viable solution other than to store passwords in the database in some fashion.  However, given that the server/certificate authority must send a password to a remote website (which I do not own or control), I don't yet see how this solution will actually allow the server to present the real password to the remote website in the POST request.  To clarify, there are really three actors here:  (A) the user, (B) the server, and (C) the remote website.  (C) is expecting the password from (B), and I want (B) to be able to provide it without talking to (A) every time.

Comment: There is no password to send. The certificate doesn't need to be unlocked with a password. Read about SSL at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer. A useful concrete example using Subversion is http://joseph.freivald.com/linux/2009/05/14/subversion-ssl-and-apache-for-secure-passwordless-user-based-repository-access-controls/.

Comment: The remote website will not implement a certificating authority.  It's Tumblr, in case that helps.  I am building a site that communicates with Tumblr.  They require that a submit a username and password as POST data.  It's a requirement of their API.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have to send the password in clear-text and do it repeatedly without user-interaction you'll need to store and retrieve the same from a data-store (file/database/memory).

What you really need to consider is the last-line-of-security of the password store.

Whether you encrypt it or not doesn't matter. The person/program with access to the data or the cipher key will be able to read that password.

Sort this issue out, document it - (this becomes your security policy for the app) and then implement it.

*Security is only a level of difficulty you implement to lessen a risk.*

Comment: Thanks, Ryan.  Your approach seems to suggest that storing the passwords in the database is not _inherently_ a practice to be avoided, but that, instead, I should consider whether avoiding such storage is the best way to provide security to my site.  This leads me to think I can store the passwords in a way that is secure.  I need a secure method that is two-way (i.e., my web application can decrypt the passwords but others cannot).  Is there anything like this?  Can you recommend something?  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: >"This leads me to think I can store the passwords in a way that is secure." - should read, "secure enough for my purpose". So, you can encrypt the password, and secure the key - now, securing the key is your last-line to secure. If your method of securing this key, in a way you feel that only the web application can access it, is your solution, then yes, that becomes your security level, and you must accept the possible risks that are associated with that method (there will be at least one, trust me). There is no end to security, just the level of risk that you accept.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, Tumblr now implements OAuth, which solves this problem.